# How to pass a tag from a tag in django?

Tags: python, html, django, video

I have a custom template filter, that replaces different markdown with html tags, so, for example, `[b][/b]` is replaced with `<b></b>` etc. 
And I need to replace the link to a video surrounded by `[video]` markdown with an actual video tags. I found an application **'django-embed-video'** that handles all possible formats and can embed youtube videos. To use it, I need to include a `{% video %}` tag in a template. 
But is there any way to pass that tag as a return value from another tag (my filter). Do you have any ideas how could I do it without copying a logic from embed-video app into my filter?

EDIT: 
I forget, that tag can be used as a function inside custom template tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this: Replace [video] by {% video %} in your filter. Get the output string and enter it as input value of "safe" filter. For example:

```
{% with html_string=different_markdown|your_filter %}
    {{html_string|safe }}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: I realised, that I can use tag as a function. Edited the question.